# How to get lowercase results from the input and compare them to other results and differentiate them from other similar results?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started learning python recently and I'm learning it from the book "Learn python the hard way". As a task I'm supposed to create my own text game. But I'm stuck with this one issue.
Is there a way for me to make it so when I type in "I don't open the door" in the input that it doesn't run the if-statement? Also I want to make all the results lowercase just to prevent any possible errors due to upper and lowercase usage.

```
def hall():
    print("You entered the gate and you are in a long hall.")
    print("You see a wooden door to your right side.")
    print("What do you do?")

    open_door = str.lower("open")
    next_move = str.lower(input("> "))

    words = next_move.split()

    if open_door in words:
        print("You open the door and enter a dark room.")
        print("Sentence 2")
        print("Sentence 3")
        dead("Sentence 4")
    else:
        continue_forward()
```

I want it to run if-statement when I type in "I open the door" but not when I type in "I don't open the door.
I've tried adding new variable such as do_not_open and using it as elif in this statement but it mixes it and it doesn't work.

```
def hall():
    print("You entered the gate and you are in a long hall.")
    print("You see a wooden door to your right side.")
    print("What do you do?")

    open_door = str.lower("open")
    do_not_open = str.lower("don't")
    do_not_open2 = str.lower("do not")
    do_not_open3 = str.lower("dont")
    next_move = str.lower(input("> "))

    words = next_move.split()

    if open_door in words:
        print("You open the door and enter a dark room.")
        print("Sentence 2.")
        print("Sentence 3")
        dead("Sentence 4")
    elif do_not_open or do_not_open2 or do_not_open3 in words:
        print("You continue through the hall.")
        hall2()
    else:
        continue_forward()
```

Even here when I type in "I open the door" it works, but when I type in "I don't open the door" it doesn't work and it just runs the if open_door in words... And only time it works is when I specifically type in the values such as "don't" or "do not".
Here is the example:

```
PS C:\Users\...> python ex35v2.py
You are in a dark forest.
You see a dim light in front of you. Do you go forward?
> yes
You approach the tall metal gate.
There is a button on the side of it.
Do you press it?
> yes
The gate opens. Do you go in?
> yes
You go inside and the gate closes.
You entered the gate and you are in a long hall.
You see a wooden door to your right side.
What do you do?
> I open the door
You open the door and enter a dark room.
Sentence 2
Sentence 3
Sentence 4 Better luck next time!
PS C:\Users\...> python ex35v2.py
You are in a dark forest.
You see a dim light in front of you. Do you go forward?
> yes
You approach the tall metal gate.
There is a button on the side of it.
Do you press it?
> yes
The gate opens. Do you go in?
> yes
You go inside and the gate closes.
You entered the gate and you are in a long hall.
You see a wooden door to your right side.
What do you do?
> I don't open the door
You open the door and enter a dark room.
Sentence 2
Sentence 3
Sentence 4 Better luck next time!
PS C:\Users\...> python ex35v2.py
You are in a dark forest.
You see a dim light in front of you. Do you go forward?
> Yes
You approach the tall metal gate.
There is a button on the side of it.
Do you press it?
> yes
The gate opens. Do you go in?
> YES
You go inside and the gate closes.
You entered the gate and you are in a long hall.
You see a wooden door to your right side.
What do you do?
> Don't
You continue through the hall.
Hall sentence 2
Hall sentence 3
Hall sentence 4
Hall sentence 5
> clear
Hall sentence 6
Hall sentence 7
Hall sentence 8
> clear
Hall sentence 9
Hall sentence 10 Better luck next time!
PS C:\Users\...> python ex35v2.py
You are in a dark forest.
You see a dim light in front of you. Do you go forward?
> yes
You approach the tall metal gate.
There is a button on the side of it.
Do you press it?
> YES
The gate opens. Do you go in?
> YEs
You go inside and the gate closes.
You entered the gate and you are in a long hall.
You see a wooden door to your right side.
What do you do?
> Do NOT
You continue through the hall.
Hall sentence 2
Hall sentence 3
Hall sentence 4
Hall sentence 5
.
.
.
```

If there is a possible way to make this actually work, please let me know.

Comment: You can't do this `do_not_open or do_not_open2 or do_not_open3 in words` you'll have to check each manually or regex to check for multiple words in `words`

Comment: You understand that the case where you respond ` I don't open the door` yields a list like ['I',"don't",'open','door'] open is in the list.  perhaps you should change the logic - if "don't" not in words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm quite new I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but I ran the code myself and it seems to work. I've actually done the same exercise before but it was a lot more simple.

```
def hall():
    print("You entered the gate and you are in a long hall.")
    print("You see a wooden door to your right side.")
    print("What do you do?")

    open_door = "open"
    do_not_open = "don\'t"
    do_not_open2 = "do not"
    do_not_open3 = "dont"
    do_not_open4 = "not"
    next_move = input("> ").lower()

    words = next_move.split()

    if open_door in words:
        if do_not_open not in words:
            print("You open the door and enter a dark room.")
            print("Sentence 2.")
            print("Sentence 3.")
            dead("Sentence 4.")
        elif do_not_open in words:
            print("You continue through the hall.")
            continue_forward()
        elif do_not_open2 in words:
            print("You continue through the hall.")
            continue_forward()
        elif do_not_open3 in words:
            print("You continue through the hall.")
            continue_forward()
        elif do_not_open4 in words:
            print("You continue through the hall.")
            continue_forward()
    elif do_not_open in words:
        print("You continue through the hall.")
        continue_forward()
    elif do_not_open2 in words:
        print("You continue through the hall.")
        continue_forward()
    elif do_not_open3 in words:
        print("You continue through the hall.")
        continue_forward()
    elif do_not_open4 in words:
        print("You continue through the hall.")
        continue_forward()
    else:
        continue_forward()
```

As I've said, I'm sure there is a cleaner and better way to do it, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error in your elif statement.

```
if var1 or var2 or var3 in valid_vars:
    print("valid")
```

this statement will output `valid` till you provide any value (other than 0 or  None or empty list, string, dict, or set ) to `var1` or `var2` OR if any of value of `valid_vars` is matched with `var3`.

To understand better, your statement is read like this

```
elif (do_not_open) or (do_not_open2) or (do_not_open3 in words):
    print("You continue through the hall.")
    hall2()
```

You should make a list of valid commands
for example

```
open_word = ['yes', 'open']
do_not_open = ['don\'t', 'do not', 'dont', 'not']
word = input('> ')
```

then make condional statements like this. (replace pass with your desired functionality)

```
if words.lower() in open_word:
    pass
elif words.lower() in do_not_open:
    pass
else:
    pass
```